# How can I protect a MySQL user from being deleted and modified?

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a MySQL user with permissions to create and remove other users, but prevent my own (superuser) account from being deleted or modified.

The user seems to need `CREATE USER` to be able to manage users, and this seems to allow deletion of all accounts.

Goal is to provide MySQL as a service with the possibility to do some user management, while keeping an administrative user on the database protected from users.

*Edit*: Users will be connecting to MySQL directly using the CLI mysql client or a third party database tool. Of course this problem could be eliminated by providing the user a custom system to do user management and do custom access control in there, but I'd prefer to give direct access to the DB.

Comment: In your scenario, is MySQL being accessed directly or via some kind of website/API?

Comment: If you were using any layer between the server and the app, such as a jdbc driver, you could just intercept the queries and block any attempt to delete your user. But since you're allowing the user to connect via mysql client, I think the best you could do was to periodically check if your user were deleted and recreate it automatically. But I still think you should think twice if granting this permission to end users is a good idea (maybe it's not)

Comment: @Leo: I wouldn't mind recreating the user every time I need it if it wouldn't mean taking down the DB and temporarily restarting it with --skip-grant-tables every time.

Comment: I agree it would be painful

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not provide this level of control over user management. But I can imagine a small application of your own that would let your authorised users to manage only users you allow.

Only the application would connect to the database as a privileged user.
Only the application would issue the actual `CREATE USER` and `DROP USER` statements, and only on accounts that you allow.

Having manipulated these actual MySQL system users via this application, these accounts would become available for direct connection.